# write log files in my webapps/application directory on tomcat

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds

I write a flex + java application using the blazeds framework.
when i write log files in my java classes the default path is the java path on the server.
I want it to be my application at the tomcat/webapps/application directory
when i write it hard-coded it failed (maybe bacause of permissions)
but, i want it to be general (not hard-coded)
so, what do i need to change in my java code in order to write files in my webapps directory?
maybe it just an xml configuration?
what do i need to do?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I need to use this method: System.getProperty("catalina.base")

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you've figured out how to do it.

But I'd like to suggest to you that it is a *better* idea to put log files in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs`.  The problem with putting log files in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/yourApp` is that they are liable to be clobbered if you redeploy your WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

also easy cheezy on unix is to put a symlink in your webapps/application directory to the log directory and add log to the url.